# Mootools calling class method onSuccess Ajax

Tags: ajax, mootools

I'm  trying to achieve the following:

1. User clicks on an element and the cmove function is invoked (works)
2. cmove passes an JS object to the ajax method (works)
3. ajax method submits the object to the move/test controller (PHP/CodeIgniter) (works)
4. controller returns some JSON Data (works)
5. onSucces calls the move method to do some stuff (no chance calling that method)

So, how can I call the move method out of the onSuccess? And is there a better way of pushing the moveObj around?

```
var Plane = new Class({
    Implements: Options,

    options: {
        action: null
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
        $('somelement').addEvent('click', this.cmove.bind(this));
    },


    cmove: function(event, action) {

        moveObj = new Object();
        moveObj.x = 123;            

        this.ajax('cmove', moveObj);

    },
    move: function(moveObj) {
        console.log("Yippe!");  // not getting here :(              
    },      

    ajax: function(action, obj) {

        resp = $('resp');

        var myRequest = new Request.JSON({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('move/test'); ?>',
            method: 'get',
            onRequest: function(){
                resp.set('text', 'wait...');
            },

            onSuccess: function(responseText){

                switch(action)
                {
                case 'cmove':

                    test3.move(responseText); // not working
                    this.move(responseText);  // not working
                    parent.move(responseText);  // not working

                    resp.set('text', responseText.x);
                    break;              


            },
            onFailure: function(){
                resp.set('text', 'Sorry, your request failed :(');
            }
        }).send('coords='+ JSON.encode(obj));           

    }

});


window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var test3= new Plane({});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to bind the callback function for the Request instance to the scope of your class or save a reference of your class' instance (`self = this`) and call via that instead:

```
ajax: function(action, obj) {

    var self = this; // save a refrence
    var resp = document.id("resp");

    new Request.JSON({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('move/test'); ?>',
        method: 'get',
        onRequest: function(){
            resp.set('text', 'wait...');
        },

        onSuccess: function(responseText){

            switch(action) {
                case 'cmove':

                    self.move(responseText); // will work
                    this.move(responseText);  // will also work

                break;              
            }

        }.bind(this), // binding callback to instance so this.method works
        onFailure: function(){
            resp.set('text', 'Sorry, your request failed :(');
        }
    }).send('coords='+ JSON.encode(obj));           

}
```